# Moving inside Json with name starting with '@'

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json that I have to get data from

```
var a ={ '@odata.context': 'https',
  '@odata.count': 9470,
  '@search.facets':
   { 'CUST_NAME_ABBR@odata.type':'#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01.QueryResultFacet)',
    CUST_NAME_ABBR: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
}
```

When I try 'a.@odata.context' I am getting the error

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

How to use this json

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Since your keys aren't valid identifiers, you should use the [`bracket` notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access your properties :

```
a['@odata.context']
```